# Is it necessary to upgrade to php7?

Tags: php

The latest php version is released. Do i need to upgrade my php version to latest. Whats the benefits and what if I stay to current version i.e. 5.6

Comment: If your site is running on WordPress.com then you have no control over your PHP version ( .com runs on the 7.x branch of PHP already ), sadly .com is offtopic here, are you on a self hosted site and miss-tagged?

Comment: Well sorry' for incomplete question.. well. I have self hosted website and I use WordPress.org not Wordpress.com